# SELECT query with JOIN returns duplicate of each row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a `SELECT` query to return addresses in a table associated with a certain "applicant code" and I'd like to join a table to also return (in the same row) the name of that applicant.

Therefore my query as of now is

```
SELECT a.id, a.created_at, a.updated_at, a.code, a.applicant_code, a.form_code, a.address_line_1, a.address_line_2, a.town_city, a.county_state, a.country, a.post_code, a.start_date, a.end_date, a.type, ap.first_name, ap.last_name 
                  FROM sfs_addresses a 
                  JOIN sfs_personal_details ap ON a.form_code = ap.form_code
                  WHERE a.form_code = ? AND a.applicant_code = ?
```

The query works, and I get the right columns and values in each row, but it returns 2 of each so like

```
ID
===
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
```

If I remove the JOIN it works fine. I have tried adding DISTINCT (makes no difference) I'm lost.

Comment: This implies that you have duplicates in the second table.

Comment: Ffs, you're absolutely right, I should have been referencing it through the applicant_code since there is many applicants in a form. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:  Based on this answer and the comments, the OP realized that the `JOIN` condition should be on `applicant_code` rather than `form_code`.

You have duplicates in the second table based on the `JOIN` key you are using (I question if the `JOIN` is correct).

If you just want one row arbitrarily, you can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT a.*, ap.first_name, ap.last_name 
FROM sfs_addresses a JOIN
     (SELECT ap.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ap.form_code ORDER BY ap.form_code) as seqnum
      FROM sfs_personal_details ap
     ) ap
     ON a.form_code = ap.form_code
WHERE a.form_code = ? AND a.applicant_code = ?;
```

You can replace the columns in the `ORDER BY` with *which* result you want -- for instance the oldest or most recent.

Note:  `form_code` seems like an odd `JOIN` column for a table called "personal details".  So, you might just need to fix the `JOIN` condition.

Comment: This wasn't the problem, the problem was I was referncing the JOIN by form_code, which is not unique. It should be by applicant code. Your opriginal comment was what made me aware of this, so I will make this answer as correct, or if you submit another that is more clear, I will mark that as correct. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

relation between 2 tables one to many to return non duplicate use distinct

SELECT distinct a.id, a.created_at, a.updated_at, a.code, a.applicant_code, a.form_code, a.address_line_1, a.address_line_2, a.town_city, a.county_state, a.country, a.post_code, a.start_date, a.end_date, a.type, ap.first_name, ap.last_name
FROM sfs_addresses a
JOIN sfs_personal_details ap ON a.form_code = ap.form_code
WHERE a.form_code = ? AND a.applicant_code = ?